# event.clientX and event.clientY vs event.x and event.y

Tags: javascript, performance, coordinates, var

When detecting mouse x and y coordinates, is it best to use event.clientX and event.clientY like this:

```
function show_coords(event){
  var x=event.clientX;
  var y=event.clientY;
  alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
}
```

or use x and y, like this:

```
function show_coords(event){
  var x=event.x;
  var y=event.y;
  alert("X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
}
```

Is one method better/faster than the other? They seem to work identically to me.

Comment: `clientX` is more cross browser, but still not for all browsers (like FireFox).

Comment: `event.x` is specified in the W3C working drafts, but not supported in many browsers? You'd be better off with `clientX`, or really any of the others, `offsetX`, `pageX` etc. `clientX` is the currently reccommended standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess event.x/y are defined only in IEs. A quote from IE documentation:

> "`event.clientX`: Retrieves the x-coordinate of the mouse cursor relative to the client area of the window, excluding window decorations or scroll bars."
>
> "`event.x`: Retrieves the x-coordinate of the mouse cursor relative to the parent element."

As putvande stated, `clientX` maybe not cross-browser either. `pageX/Y` might be a safer choice.